# convert list with keys & values to json format( python)

Tags: python, json, string, list, converters

code i am using

show_config = self.show_task(ha_task)
show_config = show_ha_config["tasks"][0]["task-details"][0][
"output"
]

```
    # need to decode into base64
    show_decoded = base64.b64decode(
        bytes(show_config, "utf-8")
    ).decode("ascii")
    show_conf = show_decoded.split("\n")
    return show_conf
```

```py
return show_conf = [
    '',
    'VSID:            0   ',
    'VRID:            0   ',
    'Type:            VSX Gateway',
    'Name:            chckpt-fw1a',
    'Security Policy: VS-policy',
    'Installed at:    12Jan2023 21:57:15',
    'SIC Status:      Trust',
    'Connections number: 52',
    'Connections peak: 152',
    'Connections limit:  14900',
]
```

i am using below code to convert it into json but response is not good

```py
json_format = json.dumps(show_conf)
return json_format
```

json_format i get:

```json
["", "VSID:            0   ", '
                                  '"VRID:            0   ", "Type:            '
                                  'VSX Gateway", "Name:            '
                                      'chckpt-fw1a", "Security Policy: '
                                      'VS-policy", "Installed at:    '
                                      '12Jan2023 21:57:15", "SIC Status:      '
                                      'Trust", "Connections number: 52", '
                                      '"Connections peak:   152", "Connections '
                                      'limit:  14900",]
```

json_format i need:

```json
['', 
'"VSID": "0"   ',
'"VRID": "0"   ',
'Type:   "VSX Gateway"',
'"Name": "chckpt-fw1a"',
'"Security Policy": "VS-policy"',
"Installed at":    "12Jan2023 21:57:15"',
"SIC Status":      "Trust"',
"Connections number": "52"',
"Connections peak":   "152"',
"Connections limit":  "14900"',]
```

Comment: What did you do to try and fix it?

Comment: The "output I need" is not JSON, so are you _sure_ that's what you need? (single quotes are invalid string delimiters in JSON, they _have_ to be double quotes). Also, are you sure that's the output JSON you get? Especially given that the output that you get from `json.dumps` _is_ valid JSON.

Comment: You seem to be calling several things `output`.  What does your starting data look like and what do you hope to get as ending data? I ask because you seem to "almost" have a dictionary but also seem to have a list

Comment: i tried bunch of codes from my research but nothing helpful so posted this question, what i am trying to print is keys and its values in readable json format, i am not sure how to get of the white spaces if output im getting is valid json

Comment: What keys? You're starting with a list of strings, not a dictionary, there are no keys, only indexed string values. The JSON equivalent of that is an array of strings. As for _readable_ JSON: use `json.dumps(some_var_name, indent=...)` with however many spaces you need for indentation (just like how you need to specify indentation in JavaScript's `JSON.stringify`), instead of only `json.dumps(some_var_name)`.

Comment: Do you have a valid dictionary or json at some point prior to `output` that you just want to format in a nice way?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert each string in the input list to a key/value pair first?

Comment: Your data is malformed to begin with. It's almost like you have individual dictionary key:value pairs embedded in each element of a list object. Clean that up first with something like `output_clean={x.split(":")[0].strip() if ':' in x else '': x.split(":")[1].strip() if ':' in x else '' for x in output}` Then you can `json.dumps` that.

Comment: in my question "output" is the data which  i got by decoding encoded data using below which gave me a list (<class 'list'>)

show_decoded = base64.b64decode(
            bytes(show_config, "utf-8")
        ).decode("ascii")
        output = show_decoded.split("\n")

so i dumped my "output" data into json using below and trying to get what i need

json_format = json.dumps(output)
return json_format

Comment: Does `json_format = json.dumps({x.split(":")[0].strip() if ':' in x else '': x.split(":")[1].strip() if ':' in x else '' for x in output})` do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably first want to **convert this list to dictionary**. To do this, we first need to parse each item in it and then dump it all to a string / file.

```py
import json  # Python built-in json parser

# Raw data
output = [
    '',
    'VSID:            0   ',
    'VRID:            0   ',
    'Type:            VSX Gateway',
    'Name:            chckpt-fw1a',
    'Security Policy: VS-policy',
    'Installed at:    12Jan2023 21:57:15',
    'SIC Status:      Trust',
    'Connections number: 52',
    'Connections peak: 152',
    'Connections limit:  14900',
]

# Declaring the dictionary for output
output_dict = {}

# Iterating through each item of `output` list
for item in output:
    # Lets take this item as sample - 'VSID:            0   '

    # Split the string by `: ` separator to list. Separator WILL be removed.
    # Result will look like this -
    #     ['VSID', '           0   ']
    splitted = item.split(": ")

    # Skip empty items or single keys
    if len(splitted) <= 1:
        continue

    output_dict[
        splitted[0].strip()  # Key - 'VSID'
    ] = splitted[1].strip()  # Value - '0'
    # `.strip()` will remove all the trailing and leading whitespaces

# Dump the generated dictionary to this variable as string.
# `indent=4` will generate the output in more human-readable format.
jsn = json.dumps(output_dict, indent=4)

# Display the json
print(jsn)
```